# Using parameter and variable in function arguments in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function type react component:

```
function Card(props, {icon}) {
    return (
        <div className="card">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon} className="icon"/>
            <h3 className="text">{props.name}</h3>            
        </div>
    )
}
```

and I want to have 2 attributes for it: `name` and `icon` 
But to display the name in my title I need to use the `props.name` but the icon is just an attribute. When I pass the arguments like that I only get the name, and if I only pass the icon, I'm able to get the icon, but I can't manage to have them both. (The icon is a Fontawesome component).

I'm calling it in my App.js like this:

```
<Card name="Folder" icon="folder"/>
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Card name="Folder" icon="folder"/>
```

Your props object now looks like

```
const props = {
   name: "Folder",
   icon: "folder",
}
```

we can then use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) when we pass it into our component.

```
function Card({icon, name}) {
    return (
        <div className="card">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon} className="icon"/>
            <h3 className="text">{name}</h3>            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Excellent, be sure to make it as the answer.